# Xamarin : BroadCastReceiver Send Notification with Tap Event that open a Popup

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am developing a Print Service App in Xamarin, this App/service talks to a server by making POST requests.
The server do require the client to enter his/her credentials by sending a http 401  response back to the service. Once the 401 response is received I'm sending a Notification and the user must tap the notification to open a custom popup and enter username/password.

Due to the limitations of running a service I'm using a broadcastReceiver to send my Notification Like this:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    const string NOTIFICATION_ID = "1000";
        Android.Content.Context _context;
        Android.Content.Intent _intent;
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //Toast.MakeText(context, "Received broadcast in MyBroadcastReceiver", 
             ToastLength.Long).Show();
            this._context = context;
            this._intent = intent;
            if (intent.Action.Equals("MYNOTIFICATION")) 
                _ = CreateNotification("Authentication Required", "Tap to enter credentials");            
        }
        
        private async Task CreateNotification(String title, String message)
        {
            await Task.Run( () =>
            {
                var intent = new Intent(_context, typeof(AuthActivity));
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
                intent.PutExtra(title, message);
                var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(_context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

                var sound = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource + "://" + _context.PackageName + "/" + Resource.Raw.notification);
            
                var alarmAttributes = new Android.Media.AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .SetContentType(Android.Media.AudioContentType.Sonification)
                    .SetUsage(Android.Media.AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build();

                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context, NOTIFICATION_ID);
                mBuilder.SetContentTitle(title)
                        .SetSound(sound)
                        .SetAutoCancel(true)
                        .SetContentText(message)
                        .SetChannelId(NOTIFICATION_ID)
                        .SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.High)
                        .SetVibrate(new long[0])
                        .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
                        .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
                        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
                        .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager = _context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

                if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= global::Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    NotificationImportance importance = global::Android.App.NotificationImportance.High;

                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_ID, title, importance);
                    notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
                    notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
                    notificationChannel.SetSound(sound, alarmAttributes);
                    notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
                    notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
                    notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

                    if (notificationManager != null)
                    {
                        mBuilder.SetChannelId(NOTIFICATION_ID);
                        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                    }
                }
                 notificationManager.Notify(0, mBuilder.Build());
            });

}
```

How can I handle the Tap event of the notification to open a custom popup without opening the App.

Comment: `How can I handle the Tap event of the notification to open a custom popup without opening the App.` Since you use `broadcastReceiver ` to achieve your function,you can't use broadcastReceiver alone, you have to add your code into your app  and launch your application.  So, the functionality you're talking about is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it right.
It's impossible to get any type of page/popup with the app being close, what i needed to do was from my Notification tap event I open an activity with a transparent background.

I used this style

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

And in the AndroidManifest.xml i referenced it, like below:

```
android:theme="@style/PopupTheme"
```

Now, On the mainActivity.cs i toggle between my transparent theme and mainbase theme using an intent.

Hope this help someone in need.